# Removing pod dependency from podspec and add it from elsewhere

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I’m looking to understand if it’s possible to remove a pod dependency on my podspec and add it from elsewhere like the podfile.

I have been doing some searching online, but I couldn’t find anything on this topic. My guess will be that this is not possible, but looking to see if there’s a way to do this.

Currently, removing the pod dependency from my podspec and add it to the podfile, it allows me to run pod install properly, but I can’t compile the project as my development pod that had the dependency fails to import the dependency into the development pod for usage.

Is there another way to do this? Or if the way mentioned above is supposed to work, how’s the correct way of doing it as it’s currently not compiling for me.

Thank you’

Comment: The podspec should describe all of its necessary dependencies. Sharing the specific example may help to provide a more specific answer

Comment: @PaulBeusterien So, it's not possible to inject a dependency via a podfile or another way besides the podspec?

Comment: you might be able to hack an Xcode project, but the podspec itself won't be publishable or usable by other clients.